# Linked tables- issue with multiple users

Tags: excel, ms-access, linked-tables

I'm fairly new to access so apologies for any silly questions.

I have a database with a linked table to excel. The excel spreadsheet is updated frequently.

I then have queries on access which allows a user to search for certain data from the linked table. However, currently when more than one person tries to use the database or run a search they either get an error forcing them to open excel spreadsheet or the excel document automatically opens in the background.

I need to prevent excel from open automatically but can't find a work around.

Due to the spreadsheet being updated daily a linked table seemed my best option.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: this may not help, but does each user have a unique front-end copy of the database?

Comment: No I will give this a try and get each user to save a version each and see if this clears up the issue. Thanks for the suggestion